# Python LF line separator problem when working with Git

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am using PyCharm on Windows, and have set the Python's line separator to `LF`.

I pushed my python file (using `LF`) to git, and when other people on the team fetch this file (also on Windows using `LF`), when they open this python file, it automatically changes to `CRLF`, I would ask how to configure to keep `LF` when others get my file from git.

Thanks

Comment: this is a too broad question

Answer (score 1):

Your team should sit and decide of a single format and guidelines to use (end of lines, indent, coding style and so on) and everybody should configure their environment (use `editorconfig` for example) to respect what is decided.
This being said, I don't think this is a Git situation.